# How to pass data from page to widget functions?

Tags: widgets, functions

I need help,need to pass data from page,to widget function,I need to pass author id to widget,any idea?
Tnx

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to read the global `$post` variable in your widget function. This will contain all information about the post (or page) displayed on the current page.

Comment: Ok,but in that way,if we are not on page where we dont have global $post var,how to find id of author,for example if we are on archive page,where we list all post from one category?

Comment: @user1147: The author of which post do you want? On an archive page you can still rewind the loop and go over every displayed post to collect the authors. If you want one specific post, you can use get_post() to query for it.